# Send SMS from service

Tags: java, android

I tried to send sms from my service when a match happens

I tried to do interface in my service and write the function in other activity. but I don't know how to call my function in the service, and if there is another solution.

```
public interface smsSender{
       void sendSms(String phoneNum);
   } //the interface in my service

//in other class
@Override
   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
       super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
       switch (requestCode)
       {
           case 0:
               if(grantResults.length >=0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
               {
                   sendSms("00000000");
               }
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void sendSms(String phoneNum) {
       int permissionCheck= ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS);
       if(permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
       {
           final SmsManager smgr = SmsManager.getDefault();

           DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

           smgr.sendTextMessage(phoneNum,null,"String in sms",null,null);




       }
       else
       {
           ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},0);
       }

   }
```

how can I call this function from service or there is a better way to send SMS from service

Comment: `sendTextMessage()` does not require an activity. Requesting the permission requires an activity, so you do that before you start the service. If the service finds that it does not have permission, it shows a `Notification` or something to let the user know that it cannot send text messages.

Comment: before starting the services make sure that user allow permission and then send an sms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that sens sms permission is declared in manifest file as

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

next to send SMS use SMSManager API

```
SmsManager smgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
smgr.sendTextMessage(MobileNumber,null,Message,null,null);
```

Please find the below sample code

```
 try{
                SmsManager smgr = SmsManager.getDefault();
                smgr.sendTextMessage(txtMobile.getText().toString(),null,txtMessage.getText().toString(),null,null);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "SMS Failed to Send, Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

In Service use the below code

```
 SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
                                    // if message length is too long messages are divided
                                    List<String> messages = sms.divideMessage(message);
                                    for (String msg : messages) {

                                        PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("SMS_SENT"), 0);
                                        PendingIntent deliveredIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent("SMS_DELIVERED"), 0);
                                        sms.sendTextMessage(phone, null, msg, sentIntent, deliveredIntent);

                                        Toast.makeText(context, "SMS Sent to: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
```